# A bunch of duos

Tags: riddle, poetry, limerick

My friend, disappointingly, just left to go somewhere without telling me. He was supposed to produce my classical techno-fusion jazz metal rap album! Instead, he left me four riddles, each with two-letter-long solutions, to piece together his whereabouts. He already gave me the solution to the last riddle, "NK."

> 1) I'm truly the first two in "go back to the start";
>   Obey me you must if you've mastered the art.
>   Halting's not smart;
>   It hasn't ended;
>   Please let me remind of the part I appended. _ _
>
> 2) I can show imagination, I can show you what's real;
>   Let me show you the unheard, it's what I reveal.
>   I frequently wander,
>   And pass time as you ponder;
>   How all  that you've heard is only piecemeal. _ _
>
> 3) "Press" on those keys, oh "tug" on those strings;
>   Do both and you'll make a rise and tide out of things;
>   Now split them in half;
>   That's it, don't laugh;
>   Or flip "down" two-fold like it's a drum stick spinning. _ _
>
> 4) NK

Can you help me solve the first three and tell me where he went? It better have been worth it - studio recording time is expensive.

**Hint 1:**

> 1) A phrase's first two letters;
>  2) Initials;
>  3) Two letters borne out of splitting either of two words in half. Using either word should suffice.

**Hint 2:**

> There's a vague theme across this entire riddle, including the non-highlighted text. Solving #3 first might engender ideas on what #1 and #2 may be.

**Hint 3:**

> Riddle 2 is by far the hardest. I want to draw your attention to the idea that every sound you hear is almost never just one "sound". A pure sine wave is the exception. A mathematician, of all things, may be most qualified to solve this.

Comment: Are we supposed to know if it's one, two, or more words? Or is that for us to determine?

Comment: @TCooper Good question, it's for you to determine. If you have the correct six letters the solution should be plain to see, I think.

Comment: Blargh, I know the second one now - something I hoped I'd never have to look at again...!

Comment: LOL I apologize for that Stiv

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The duos that this puzzle clue all add up to reveal another duo:

> **[DAFT PUNK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daft_Punk)**

1. *I'm truly the first two in "go back to the start"; Obey me you must if you've mastered the art. Halting's not smart; It hasn't ended; Please let me remind of the part I appended.*

> As @TCooper found, this clues the two letters '**DA**', the first two letters of the musical phrase '*da capo*', which means 'go back to the start'. It also begins the word 'DAFT' (more on that later), which means 'not smart' - so if that hasn't ended, we've got the first two letters 'DA' clued again...

2. *I can show imagination, I can show you what's real; Let me show you the unheard, it's what I reveal. I frequently wander, And pass time as you ponder; How all that you've heard is only piecemeal*:

> This clues the letters '**FT**'. My initial interpretation was by way of a reference to 'ft.', the abbreviation that often follows the main artist name attached to a record to credit a second performer who played a big part in its production, but might have been 'unheard' as a producer or musician (much like Mark Ronson is often credited).
>
>  Having only noticed later that the OP left a hint that this duo should represent initials for something mathematical, this is actually a reference to the '[***F***ourier **T**ransform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform)', a mathematical technique which decomposes a function into its constituent frequencies. This has big uses in signal processing, where you can break down a signal (like a sound) into its constituent parts, allowing you to pick out things that were previously 'unheard' and lurking beneath the overall effect. Delving into the technical aspects of Fourier Transforms (after a nudge from the OP), these are 'complex' in the mathematical sense and consist of two parts: one *imaginary* and one *real* (hence "*I can show **imagination**, I can show you what's **real***"). It also converts from the *time* domain to the [*frequency* domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_domain) (hence the clues hidden in "*I **frequently** wander, And pass **time** as you ponder*").

3. *"Press" on those keys, oh "tug" on those strings; Do both and you'll make a rise and tide out of things; Now split them in half; That's it, don't laugh; Or flip "down" two-fold like it's a drum stick spinning.*

> This clues the letters '**PU**'. Another phrase meaning 'press' and 'tug' is '*push and pull*'. 'Split them in half' and you see that both begin with 'PU'. These two letters also spell 'UP' backwards, which is what you get if you 'flip "down" two-fold' - once in meaning, then once in letter order.

Put these all together with the known '**NK**' fourth part and you have:

> **DAFT PUNK**. And let's face it, if you're into 'classical techno-fusion jazz metal rap' you're probably into the fusion music this 'duo' cooks up too!

Comment: Ah, well it makes sense when you put it like that. Nice one. Guessing this is right

Comment: Gotta say quite the ninja'ing of @MacGyver88. Nice job on the recognition of duos! :)  I'll grant the checkmark when someone solves #2. It's not quite "ft." but another FT. It's a technical term and hopefully someone somewhere recognizes it.

Comment: @anodyne Yeah I only spotted your hint about initials later after answering - I'm still working on that part!

Comment: rot13(Vs lbh syvc QBJA bapr, vg punatrf gb HC. Vs lbh syvc vg ntnva, lbh trg CH. Evtug?) Oh, I see you already noticed. Nevermind.

Comment: @MacGyver88 That's right. Probably the most forced clue but who can resist when drummers spin their sticks. Stiv, it's not quite that "FT" either. I'll add a hint and let it ruminate

Comment: @MacGyver88 Ha! We seem to be on exactly the same wavelength as each other tonight, just a little out of sync! What time zone are you in??! ;-)

Comment: GMT-5 I think...US EST. Making me think :) Just about to leave work.

Comment: The rot13(Sbhevre Genafsbez) is indeed correct. @Stiv, if I may nudge edits on 2: the FT is comprised of a real part and imaginary number part; when applied to an audio signal, the FT reveals, as you say, the dominant frequency as well as overtones/"unheard" frequencies of a sound, all of which add up to create a complex wave; the FT converts from the "time"-domain to the "frequency" domain. Hope this illuminates.

Comment: @anodyne Nudge taken! Think I've nailed all that down now, but feel free to holler if you need more. It's been a loooong time since I've had to think about those...!

Answer (score 4):

Trying a partial answer, maybe it'll help someone else get there.

1) I'm truly the first two in "go back to the start";
Obey me you must if you've mastered the art.
Halting's not smart;
It hasn't ended;
Please let me remind of the part I appended. _ _

> Da Capo - "an Italian musical term that means "from the beginning" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Da_capo

2) I can show imagination, I can show you what's real;
Let me show you the unheard, it's what I reveal.
I frequently wander,
And pass time as you ponder;
How all that you've heard is only piecemeal. _ _

> ??

3) "Press" on those keys, oh "tug" on those strings;
Do both and you'll make a rise and tide out of things;
Now split them in half;
That's it, don't laugh;
Or flip "down" two-fold like it's a drum stick spinning. _ _

> WA - WAx and WAne, while not exactly half for wax, as close as can be. Wasn't considering this until I thought about the don't laugh clue.

4) NK

That gives us:

> DA??WANK

Comment: 1) is correct! This should confirm for you the theme. 2) is by far the hardest. Godspeed. 3) Rise and tide, ebb and flow, __ and __...

Comment: I'll keep sporadically attempting. I might be the most musically disinclined person on all of SE, so this is strictly a research/maybe some book knowledge try for me lol
I'm assuming 3 should be obvious after that hint, but still got nothing for now.

Comment: Aha :) your answer to 1 indicates that's not true. It only seems that way because of the nature of the site, I guess. I will add that 2 is something not specific to music whatsoever, but I've described how it is. 3 is the least "technical" so no knowledge required

Comment: Your first duo suddenly made everything click for me TCooper! +1 and thanks for the flash of inspiration :)

Comment: That's why I posted Stiv, spinning my wheels too hard on this one! Glad it helped